# Multiple MainActivities start on startActivityForResult() in Android

Tags: java, android

guys,
I've been working on a native Android application for some time and now I am at the end of it there is still a problem I need help with.
[My project at github](https://github.com/mvelikov/sdiet-android)
There is the following problem - when user starts the application for the first time the app will ask him "When does your diet cycle starts?" with a datepicker popup. I am using **SharedPreferences** to store the result user has picked from the popup. I have separate **DatePickerActivity** from the **MainActivity** one that takes care of this datepicker that I start with **startActivityForResult()**. The **DatePickerActivity** passes the result to the **MainActivity** using an **Intent**.
When I debug the app I see **finish()** in **DatePickerActivity** is started twice and the **MainActivity** is started more than one this cause the datepicker popup to show once again.
Once the start date is set in the system there is no problem with these activities and application works fine.
Then comes the moment when user wants to reset the date - using the basket icon with text like "Изчисти" and the datepicker once again appear twice.

I hope I've been clear enough with my explanation and I am looking fowrard to hearings from you.
Best Regards,
Mihail

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work around my problem. I guess I caused it because I need my main layout redraw after user picks a date from the picker and I doing

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Here should be the reason for multiple MainActivity instances in the app. Second thing I guest is that committing SharedPreferences to the OS is async and by the time I check for selected date it has not been written yet.
I solved the problem by saving picked date in static instance and when I redraw the main layout I already have the result.
Thank to those who lost some of their time trying to fix my problem!